# Complex multi-column mysql order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I have a Product Database with products ordered by popularity (number_sold).  The problem is that many of the popular products are out of stock.  I want to sort by number_sold where in_stock is at least 1, then display the out-of-stock products afterwards (still sorted by number_sold).

**Example Data:**

```
Blue Car - stock 0 - sold 8
Red Car - stock 2 - sold 4
Yellow Car - stock 0 - sold 5
Tan Car - stock 8 - sold 1
Purple Car - stock 1 - sold 2
```

I want displayed in the following order:

```
1) Red
2) Purple
3) Tan
4) Blue
5) Yellow
```

Is this possible within one MySQL query?

Comment: Sure, just `order by (in_stock>0) desc, number_sold desc`

Comment: I think I was looking at the same DB table for too long... Solution above works perfectly for all tables / values tested.  Thanks again towr! Previous responses deleted to keep this post cleaner for any others needing the same solution :)

Comment: @towr . . . You should post an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah your right, sorry it's a bad habit of mine to just answer in comments, even though SO says not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
select * from product order by (in_stock >0) desc, number_sold desc
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b21a6/2/00)

Answer (score 0):

Order by an expression based on the stock level first, then number sold:

```
select * from products
order by in_stock = 0, number_sold desc
```

This works because in mysql true is `1` and false is `0`, so for all the in-stock products, the expression `in_stock = 0` is zero and will be sorted first. For out of stock products that expression is `1` sorting last.